# Paypal redirect to mobile native apps

Tags: paypal, returnurl, nativeapplication

I am using Paypal checkout as payment gateway for my mobile web application and it works fine.

Now I am trying to create Mobile native app (android, ios, windows) using Phonegap and facing issue while redirecting Paypal back to my mobile app.

What URL should I give as RETURURL in case of mobile native app?

Is there any way I can return user back to the mobile native app?

Thanks for your help in advance. Have a great day.

Regards... Mehul Patel

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use paypal native libraries ( ios / android ) for your native application.

http://paypal.github.io/

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK#paypal-ios-sdk

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK#paypal-android-sdk